# How to make text Indent in Webstorm

Tags: ide, webstorm

I'm using Webstorm to write my code.

my code is a mess now,

how can I arrange it nicely and do text Indent?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should select `Code | Reformat code` in main menu. Also you could control how your code will be reformatted in `Settings | Code Style`.

Additional info can be found in [WebStorm help](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/reformatting-source-code.html)

Comment: Strange, my code was indenting by 2 spaces only (despite being set to 4), but after reformatting using this, it started working correctly

Comment: As people have suggested in other answers, the shortcut to `Reformat Code` is `Ctrl + Shift + L`. I'd suggest tying this with a [editorconfig](https://editorconfig.org/) file. Works well for most projects!

Answer (score 9):

For Mac:

`Command + Alt + L`  for "Reformat Code".

`Ctrl + Alt + I` for "Auto-indent line(s)".

You can also select a block of text with the cursor and use tab or shift+tab to move the block to the right and to the left, respectively.

You can edit how your code looks further by going to `Preferences | Editor | Code Style`.

Answer (score 6):

If you are on **Windows** then:

1.Select the area of code you want to intent (use `Ctrl+A` to select all lines ).

2.Now press `Ctrl+Alt+I` to auto-intent.

Answer (score 5):

Although you can use auto-indentation but take a look at its settings,

In Webstrom or any JetBrain's IDE:

**Preferences(setting) > Editor > Code Style**

choose your playground and then changes this value to your desire:

[image]

*(Most JavaScript developers use above settings)*

Answer (score 0):

Preferences(setting) > Editor > Code Style > **HTML > Other**

**Insert new line before:** (Make sure it has body,div,etc..)

**Do not indent children of:** (Delete everything here)

Should be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeVIz.jpg

- Love dolls!